# Websphere 8.5 application Subsequent calls gives 404

Tags: java, websphere-8

I have a Java application deployed on Websphere 8.5 as an EAR and the very first call to my application `http://myodr/myapplication/service.do` works however all the subsequent calls to it fail with 404`The webpage cannot be found`.
What am I missing? 
I verified that all the JVMs and the odr is up and running from the console.

Any ideas.

Comment: All subsequent calls to the same address?
What is "odr"?

Comment: @GreenhouseVeg On demand router. Basically I go to my websphere console at something like 'http://myodr:9043/ibm/console/login.blah'.

Comment: "All the JVMs" means all application servers? Do you have more than one? Could it be that your servlet crashed in one of them?

Comment: Does it work if you address the AppServer JVM directly?